# iTunes Connect uploading issue

Tags: iphone, loader, uploading

Too bad that iTunes Connect changed its behavior recently. I'm providing an update to an existing app. I submitted new binary using the Loader without problem on the first try. Then I discovered that different from before, one has to reject the binaries in order to change screenshots.

Too bad that the update is in the status of "In Review". Well, I have to rejected my binaries and begin to upload new screenshots, because I don't want to display screenshots of previous version. The new screen shots are uploaded but I'm stuck in "Developer rejected" status. Meaning I cannot upload the binaries and not able to change screenshots from that time on. The following error will appear when click Save Changes in either situations.

> "There was an error saving changes. Please try again later or contact
>   iTunes Connect Support at itunesconnect@apple.com."

I checked the source of the error page and think it's this error

```
id="lcBoxWrapperHeaderTextUpdaterContainer"    
action="/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/7.0.0.9.7.7.1.1.1.1" errorId="ajaxContainerError"
```

I have reported iTune Connect via the "Contact us" link on this issue but not get any response back for 2 days already. Very disappointing.

Did anybody experience similar issue? How did you resolve this?

Comment: This is more of a support issue with Apple's iTunes Connect website, and not really a programming question.  I'd recommend asking in Apple's developer forums instead: http://devforums.apple.com

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I have 2 applications one for iPhone and the other for iPad. Upload on iPhone was successful but when I tried to upload iPad app it it displaying this error message. I am not able to understand what actually went wrong.. please help me..